# Pandas melt to get multiple variable and value columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame

```
data = {
"SomeCol":[1,2],
"Group1":['x','y'],
"Group2":['a','b'],
"SomeAgg":[100,200]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   SomeCol Group1 Group2  SomeAgg
0        1      x      a      100
1        2      y      b      200
```

How can I get this:

```
   SomeCol    Var1    Var2 Var1_value Var2_value  SomeAgg
0        1  Group1  Group2          x          a      100
1        2  Group1  Group2          y          b      200
```

I have tried `pd.melt` function which gives only one variable and one value columns.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The way you want the dataframe, it seems you will have to melt and merge, to cast it that way. Is that okay? As you are only melting two columns, and leaving the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can also be achieved without using `pd.melt`:

```
data = {
"SomeCol":[1,2],
"Group1":['x','y'],
"Group2":['a','b'],
"SomeAgg":[100,200]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
col_names = ['Group1', 'Group2']
df['Var1'], df['Var2'] = col_names[0], col_names[1]
df = df.rename(columns={col_names[0]: 'Var1_Value', col_names[1]: 'Var2_Value'})

print(df)

   SomeCol Var1_Value Var2_Value  SomeAgg    Var1    Var2
0        1          x          a      100  Group1  Group2
1        2          y          b      200  Group1  Group2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to multi index. This code comes straight from the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html#cookbook-multi-index

```
   row  One_X  One_Y  Two_X  Two_Y
0    0    1.1    1.2   1.11   1.22
1    1    1.1    1.2   1.11   1.22
2    2    1.1    1.2   1.11   1.22

# As Labelled Index
In [76]: df = df.set_index('row')

In [77]: df
Out[77]: 
     One_X  One_Y  Two_X  Two_Y
row                            
0      1.1    1.2   1.11   1.22
1      1.1    1.2   1.11   1.22
2      1.1    1.2   1.11   1.22

# With Hierarchical Columns
In [78]: df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(c.split('_'))
   ....:                                         for c in df.columns])
   ....: 

In [79]: df
Out[79]: 
     One        Two      
       X    Y     X     Y
row                      
0    1.1  1.2  1.11  1.22
1    1.1  1.2  1.11  1.22
2    1.1  1.2  1.11  1.22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
"SomeCol":[1,2],
"Group1":['x','y'],
"Group2":['a','b'],
"SomeAgg":[100,200]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

s1 = df.melt(id_vars=['SomeCol','SomeAgg'], value_vars=['Group1'],var_name='Var1', value_name='Var1_value')
s2 = df.melt(id_vars=['SomeCol'], value_vars=['Group2'],var_name='Var2', value_name='Var2_value')
ls = ['SomeCol','Var1','Var1','Var1_value', 'Var2_value','SomeAgg']
result = s1.merge(s2,on='SomeCol')
print(result[ls])
```